# TableView not loading cells despite there being data in array

Tags: swift

I have my table view class and Cell class. I fetch the data from an API that I know returns data(I can even see it in the debugger) but somehow the cells never load any data. Whats even more strange is that if I set a breakpoint inside of the table view datasource extension functions it will never trigger. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here is what I've done so far:

Table view controller

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainComment: UIViewController{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTable: UITableView!
    
    var arrayComments = [CommentBE]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.getPostComments();
    }
    
    func getPostComments() {
        CommentWS.getCommentsByPost(g_activePostId, success: {
            arrayComments in
            self.arrayComments = arrayComments
            self.commentTable.reloadData()
        }, error: {
            (errorMessage) in
            print(errorMessage)
        })
    }
    

    @IBOutlet weak var ViewContent: UIView!
    
}

extension MainComment: UITableViewDataSource { //number, number, cellfor
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrayComments.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cellIdentidier = "commentCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentidier, for: indexPath) as! MainCelda
        //cell.delegate = self
        cell.objComment = self.arrayComments[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Cell:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainCelda : UITableViewCell{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var commentDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var personProfilePic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var personName: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentText: UILabel!
    
    var poster: PersonBE!
    
    var objComment: CommentBE! {
        didSet {
            self.updateData()
        }
    }
        
    private func updateData() {
        self.getPoster(personId: objComment.personId)
        self.commentText.text = self.objComment.commentText
        /*
        self.imgPost.downloadImageInUrlString(Constants.image_fs + self.objPost.pictureUrl) { (image, urlString) in
            self.imgPost.image = image
        }*/
        self.personName.setTitle(self.poster.displayName, for: .normal)
    }
    
    
    func getPoster(personId: String) {        
        PersonWS.getPersonByPersonId(personId, success: {(person) in
            self.poster = person
        }, error: {(errorMessage) in
            print(errorMessage)
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be the issue, but in `getPostComments` I would make sure we’re on the main thread. You can’t reload the table on a background thread, and many API callbacks do come in on a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I set a breakpoint inside of the table view datasource extension functions it will never trigger

Maybe because you’re *not* the datasource? Let’s be certain. In `viewDidLoad`, say

```
self.commentTable.dataSource = self
```